# Ruby regex is ignoring # character

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string in Ruby

```
"  # config.autoload_paths = $(lib)\n"
```

I get a match when I try a regex match using the following

```
/\s*config.autoload_paths\s*=/
```

I'm not sure why this is a match though.  I expected the `/\s*c` part at the front of the regex to cause a match failure because of the `#` character in the string.  Any ideas why this is matching?

Comment: I won't mark this as a duplicate, but see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2104199/128421 as it explains the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`\s*c` means *any number of spaces followed by a `c`*. If you want to make it from the beginning of the line, add an anchor : `^`

Demo without anchor: [here](https://regex101.com/r/iD6kC0/1)

```
"  # config.autoload_paths = $(lib)\n"
    ⬆↳c
    Any space
```

Demo with anchor: [there](https://regex101.com/r/nH5yE1/2)

Comment: But that's not what my string has.  It has any number of spaces, followed by a #, then more spaces, THEN a c.

Comment: @CodeKing see the demos and read a bit about [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: FWIW: here's a link to the (concise) ruby documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors

Comment: Note that you almost always want `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$` (respectively) with Ruby.

Comment: @muistooshort interesting, do you have any example/ressources?

Comment: The docs orde linked to would be a start. The problem is that `^` is beginning of *line* not *string* (similarly for `$`) so newlines can trip you up if you use `^` and `$`. Using `^` or `$` without a comment saying "yes, I really mean line here" tends to suggest someone that isn't familiar with Ruby's regexes or a bug.